# Algorithm to find the longest fully-internal line of a non-regular 2D-shape?

Tags: image-processing, geometry, computer-vision, computational-geometry, shapes

I've been doing some image processing recently, and am looking for an algorithm to determine the longest line segment that is entirely within a non-regular shape. In other words, the line segment should be the longest line segment that touches the shape elusively at its endpoints.

The shape can be represented as a set of (x,y) coordinates or as a binary-array. The outermost layer of pixels (the edge), have already been determined. 
A simple example would be an ellipse, to which the solution is the major axis. A more complex example would be a equilateral triangle, which would result in a line between two pixels which are immediately adjacent to two separate corners. Most of my shapes are ellipse-like or 'worm-like' (long and wavy).

Ultimately I wish to use this as a method to divide the 'worm-like' shapes into their segments, using a series of 'cuts' approximately perpendicular to this line. I am hoping that the line formed by this message will be better suited for this task than one determined by a regression. It should be noted that these shapes are high resolution, and therefore may consist of up to 1000 edge-pixels, which is why I'm trying to avoid a simple iterative/brute force approach.

Thank you for any and all suggestions!

Here are some visualizations:

[image: Example 1] [image: Example 2]

Comment: Can you please clarify How will you sort the longest line when more than one lines are possible?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously similar to the maximum [Feret diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feret_diameter), which is one of a number of [particle-based metrics](https://www.sympatec.com/EN/Science/Characterisation/05_ParticleShape.html). Also referred to a [maximum caliper diameter](http://www.nist.gov/lispix/doc/particle-form/morph-param.htm).

Comment: @RogerRowland: the "fully-internal" constraint makes it a different and much harder problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which is why I've commented instead of answering. The OP's question actually sounds like the complexity of accounting for non-convex shapes may not be necessary. It seems all that's needed is to find the normal to the major axis of a 2D point cloud. My comment is intended to be helpful.

Comment: This would be a really good question if you could just add a sample image (or data) so that people have something to work with and another where you indicate the expected result.

Comment: @BalajiR I do not expect that occurrence in my actual use cases, however in such event, I would prefer to identify them all, and then use a heuristic to isolate the ideal choice.

Comment: @RogerRowland Thank you for the suggestion. While that may not be directly applicable to my specific issue at this stage, it may still be of use down the road or to others with a similar problem.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer on this particular question : the longest segment within a polygon. Did you found it ?

Comment: My solution to this particular problem was actually skeletonization. You may consider using PCA as in Ander's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, if I understood the question properly, that something similar to what you are trying to achieve is called *Planar shape decomposition* in Computer Vision literature. It is not exactly the same (is not finding the longest line in a shape), but is a way of *decomposing* a shape into line-separated *meaningful* segments for later shape-analysis or shape-matching operations (which might be useful for what you want).

Find bellow a sample image extracted from the latter cited paper (1):

[image]

If this is what you want to achieve (more or less), have a look to the following paper for a method to calculate shape decomposition (and refer to the bibliography for other methods):

(1) **Planar shape decomposition made easy**:
http://bmvc2015.swansea.ac.uk/proceedings/papers/paper013/index.html

Comment: Excellent reference, this addresses my greater issue **perfectly**, while fulfilling my 'worm' criteria, which was implicitly non-convex.

Answer (score 5):

I am unsure if I get the idea completely right, but to me it sounds a PCA problem, or in Computer graphics a object oriented bounding box problem.

Example:

[image]

The longest  axis of that box will be your longest line.

There are several tutorials online on how to compute this box, but the steps are quite easy:

1. Compute PCA of your points
2. Compute the projection of your points onto the first principal component
3. Get max-min
4. Reproject (max,0,0) and (min,0,0) in eigenspace to XYZ
5. Make a line between them

Note that this will only work for convex figures. An ellipsoid, triangle will be OK for this, but it will compute a diagonal for an "L" shaped geometrical object. If you know that your objects will be convex, then this is the fastest and easiest approach to get the "longest internal line" (because if it is convex all the lines between points are "internal"). If your object are non-convex, then youd need to split them into convex subsections somehow, e.g. as @imaluengo suggests.